# Why does address.transfer(amount) cost the same when sent to a new or used address?

Tags: transactions, gas, accounts, gas-estimate, address.transfer

In the Ethereum yellow-paper, it's specified that creating a new account costs 25000 gas (Appendix G, entry for Gnewaccount).

We can see this if, for example, we call a function that makes a transfer:

`function test (address receiver) public payable {
        receiver.transfer(msg.value);
}`

It costs 30356 if sent to an existing address and 55356 if sent to a new address.

The question is, why don't we see the same behavior if we make a regular ether transaction? Just calling `receiver.transfer(msg.value);` costs always 21000 gas no matter if the transaction is to a new or old address.

A new account is created, the same way as the function call, since is storing a new account on chain, shouldn't the cost be 46000?